# Retrieve a list of all facebook users using my app

Tags: facebook, api, list

I'm a developer for a management and analytic tool and I'm trying to provide some specific statistics about facebook's apps usage and some management features.

I'd like to know if there's some kind of api to retrieve a list of all users who are currently using my app. I've read the entire facebook documentation but I could not find nothing about this arguments.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you study the Facebook API when you want to know the users of your analytics tool. Can you elaborate on this a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook developer documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.isAppUser/) shows how to check if the present user is also an user of your application.

Once you get the user_access_token of the user when he grants permission to your app, make a GET request to the following URL.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userId?fields=installed&access_token=<user_access_token>
```

This will return with `installed = true` if the user with userId is an user of the application.

You can read more about `installed` field under [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) in Facebook developer documents.